# Transform values of a column in particular format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame df with a column called "Name". I have stored it separately as:

```
list = df.Name
```

This gives me result like

```
0    Christine
1    Alex
2    Brian
3    Thomas
4    Tom
```

I want to transform above output into the below form:

```
["Christine","Alex","Brian","Thomas","Tom"]
```

How can I perform this task using pandas?

Comment: `df.Name.tolist()`?

Comment: @MaxU  This gives me [u'Christine',
 u'Alex',
 u'Brian',
 u'Thomas',
 u'Tom']

Comment: What about `df.Name.values.tolist()`?

Comment: yes, your `Name` column is unicode-encoded and you're using Python 2x, which shows  unicode strings as `u'string...'`, so everything is OK

Comment: @MaxU Is there a way I can get rid of this? I don't want my output as unicode strings, because that is not recognized by my program

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri As mentioned in the above comment, this gives me output in united strings. I don't want that.

Comment: @Dreamer It is not necessary. But if you want to get rid of unicode `u`. you may call it wrapped within `map` as: `map(str, df.Name.tolist())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [18]: df.Name.tolist()
Out[18]: [u'Christine', u'Alex', u'Brian', u'Thomas', u'Tom']

In [19]: df.Name.str.encode('latin-1', 'ignore').tolist()
Out[19]: ['Christine', 'Alex', 'Brian', 'Thomas', 'Tom']
```

PS but be careful with this solution - it won't work properly for "special" unicode characters...

Comment: What do we do to make it work with "special" unicode characters?